# Google_Auth_Exception: Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_request'

Tags: google-api-php-client

I'm trying to get an access token, using the latest version of the google-api-php-client (take a look at this https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client), and I'm following this official doc:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/aaa_oauth2_web

The only difference is that I'd like to use the service `Google_Service_Plus`, instead of `Google_Service_Urlshortener`.

Basically I do these steps:

- I initialize the Google Client `$client` specifying client ID, client secret, developer key, scopes and redirect URI (which points to my localhost Ubuntu 12.04 - PHP 5.3.10).
- I initialize the Google Plus Service `$plus` using the Google Client `$client`.
- I redirect the user to the Auth URL using `$client->createAuthUrl()`.
- The user can see the Consent Page and accepts.
- I obtain an authorization code `$_GET['code']` to use for token exchange.
- Then, in the callback page, I try to do `$client->authenticate($_GET['code']);` but google server returns HTTP 400 and I get a `Google_Auth_Exception: Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_request'`.

The flow breaks here. 
What's wrong?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance, 
Niccolò.

Answer (score 8):

I created an oauth2callback.php file and was experiencing this problem.  The problem went away when I setup my Google_Client properly.  At first I was only setting the clientId and secret.  As soon as I set the redirectUri, my code started working.  I didn't think I needed to set the redirectUri since I know the redirect had already occurred (I was on the redirect page).  I figured this answer might help others experiencing a similar problem.

Comment: This was exactly my problem. Since I am using `server-side-flow`, the redirectUri had to be set to "`postmessage`". Then, voila!

Comment: What does `postmessage` mean? @CJThompson

Answer (score 4):

Once I set the JSON configuration file for the $client, it worked for me.

Example:`$client->setAuthConfigFile(__dir__.'/../conf/client_secrets.json');`

Comment: In my case, I forgot to set client secret.